# Bash script to take CPU temperature and CPU usage and save this values every second to file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cpu, temperature

I need to write script or command line code in Ubuntu which take CPU temperature and % of CPU usage from lm_sensors or something similar. This information I would like to save to .txt file with date and time of each measurement. I tried to write .sh file which is below. But it doesn't work as I would like to.
Can somebody help me?

```
while true;
do
echo $( date '+%H:%M:%S' ): $( sensors | grep 'CPU Temperature' | sed -r 's/^.*:        +(.*)  +[(].*$/\1/' ) >> temperature.txt;
echo $( date '+%H:%M:%S' ): $( top -b -n 1 | grep 'CPU:') >> cpu.txt;
sleep 1; 
done
```

Comment: Your script lacks a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: I miss it when I paste this code here.I hope someone had similar problem and can share his own code :).

Comment: Sensors on my machine doesn't have 'CPU Temperature' so I had to use ``'Package'`` instead or ``'Core'``. 

Also, top on my machine doesn't have 'CPU:' but it has ``'Cpu(s):'``

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: what is your processor? turbostat (linux-tools-common) will do exactly what you want, if it works with your processor. Also, reduce the sampling rate to about 5 seconds, otherwise you might be waking CPUs just to measure stuff.

Comment: This script will create a 172,800 line logfile daily. Remember to rotate it!

Comment: In what way " it doesn't work as I would like to."? Does it do anything?

Comment: @MartinThornton, when I run script it create only temperature.txt and now I know that it's my mistake because temperature.txt and cpu.txt are in one loop. When I comment line with " echo $( date '+%H:%M:%S' ): $( sensors | grep 'CPU Temperature' | sed -r 's/^.*:        +(.*)  +[(].*$/\1/' ) >> temperature.txt; " It creates cpu.txt file with some measurements. I compare this measurements with psensors program and I see for example at 12:28:45 in cpu.txt value of cpu % usage is 8,5% but in psensors window at this time cpu % value is 100%. That's my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Sysfs is a better source for parsing attributes exposed by kernel subsystems.

```
echo "scale=1; $(sort -nr /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/{temp1_input,temp2_input,temp3_input} | head -n1) / 1000" | bc
```

Output:

**38.0**

Linux CPU utilization:

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Linux_CPU_utilization#UNIX_Shell

```
#!/bin/bash

# by Paul Colby (http://colby.id.au), no rights reserved ;)

# Temperature inputs.
TEMP_INPUT=$(echo /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/{temp1_input,temp2_input,temp3_input})

PREV_TOTAL=0
PREV_IDLE=0

while true; do
  # Get the total CPU statistics, discarding the 'cpu ' prefix.
  CPU=(`sed -n 's/^cpu\s//p' /proc/stat`)
  IDLE=${CPU[3]} # Just the idle CPU time.

  # Calculate the total CPU time.
  TOTAL=0
  for VALUE in "${CPU[@]}"; do
    let "TOTAL=$TOTAL+$VALUE"
  done

  # Calculate the CPU usage since we last checked.
  let "DIFF_IDLE=$IDLE-$PREV_IDLE"
  let "DIFF_TOTAL=$TOTAL-$PREV_TOTAL"
  let "DIFF_USAGE=(1000*($DIFF_TOTAL-$DIFF_IDLE)/$DIFF_TOTAL+5)/10"

  # Calculate highest CPU Temperature.
  HIGH_TEMP=$(echo "scale=1; $(sort -r $TEMP_INPUT | head -n1) / 1000" | bc)

  # Redirect CPU temperature and % of CPU usage to file.
  echo "$(date '+%H:%M:%S'): +${HIGH_TEMP}°C ${DIFF_USAGE}%" >> cpu.txt

  # Remember the total and idle CPU times for the next check.
  PREV_TOTAL="$TOTAL"
  PREV_IDLE="$IDLE"

  # Wait before checking again.
  sleep 1
done
```

Output cpu.txt:

**12:02:27: +38.0°C 6%**